# Why can't I assign an Array of Dog(s) to an array of Animal(s) in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, protocols

Ok, let me better explain what I mean.

### Array and Classes

Let's say I have these 2 classes:

```
class Animal { }
class Dog: Animal { }
```

I **CAN** now write the following code and the compiler is totally happy.

```
var animals = [Animal]()
let dogs = [Dog]()
animals = dogs
```

> This is possible because in Swift Array is a Struct, so it's a value type and therefore the `dogs` array is copied (at least at conceptual level untill a change is made to `animals` or `dogs`).
>
> So there is no risk that writing this `animals.append(Animal())` I put an `Animal` inside the `dogs` Array. Infact `animals` and `dogs` are 2 distinct values. This would not be possible if `Array` were an `Object` like in Java.

### Let's try with protocols!

Let's now define `Animal` and `Dog` like protocols

```
protocol Animal { }
protocol Dog: Animal { }
```

Now this code makes the compiler pretty **unhappy**

```
var animals = [Animal]()
let dogs = [Dog]()
animals = dogs
^ error: cannot assign value of type '[Dog]' to type '[Animal]'
```

Can you explain me why this is **NOT** possible?

> I am using Swift 2.2.

Comment: I had same issue a while back. This answer helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237753/conform-to-protocol-mkannotation-via-custom-protocol

Comment: We've both discussed this a lot already recently, but check out this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33090626/swift-upcasting-array-of-protocol-to-array-of-super-protocol-causes-error

Comment: you to convert it dog into animal before assign it as a animal animals = dogs as! Animal

Comment: @TysonVignesh: your code does not compile. You cannot force cast `dogs` to `Animal`.

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz: your link perfectly explains the reason why this is not possibile. Thanks.

Comment: @dfri: Ok just marked it.